# Having early access to Wild Shape but being able to Wild Shape into animals

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, druid, wild-shape

I know that if you want to Wild Shape at a level before 5 when you get it as a regular Druid or a Wild Shape Ranger, there are a few options (Divine Minion, Totem Druid), but the downside to these abilities is that you get a variant version of Wild Shape that does not grant you the whole suite of regular animal forms normally included with Wild Shape.

I have been thinking about solutions to this: either WS Ranger 1/Druid 1 with the Divine Minion template, OR Totem Druid 1/WS Ranger 1. Both put you a level 2, though the first requires no multiclassing and nets you a tempalte.

This question comes from an optimization point of view: I want to get the most out of Wild Shape and both Planar Shepherd and Master of Many Forms. A build of Totem Druid 1/MoMF 4/Planar Shepherd 9/MoMF 6) gets me far, but it would mean that I cannot turn into the quite useful repertoire of normal animals. So my question is as follows:

**Is it possible to access the Wild Shape ability at lower-than-usual (<5) while still being able to Wild Shape into natural animals?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The literature on the subject suggests that you've found all routes:

- The [planar shepard handbook](http://community.wizards.com/forum/previous-editions-character-optimization/threads/1081076) recommends Druid/5 as entry
- Updated [Master of many forms bible](http://community.wizards.com/forum/previous-editions-general/threads/1060931) makes no mention of early entry
- The incomprehensible but occasionally useful [early entry handbook](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=11734.msg199930#msg199930) (point 9 on that post) has no useful suggestions.
- And the [druid handbook](http://www.minmaxboards.com/index.php?topic=940) has no useful suggestions.

In short, enjoy your first five levels as an excellent class.

Answer (score 3):

## Yes, But...

1. *only* if the DM allows creatures to meet prestige class requirements using magic items, **and**...
2. *only* if the DM allows a Drd1 to acquire somehow the *correct* magic item.

[Only the DM prevents creatures from meeting with magic items prerequisites and requirements](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/23119/8610), but talk to the DM. Many folks think that doing so is shady, lazy, or cheap, but committing a *different* resource to solve a problem is *still* committing a resource to solve a problem, so if the DM allows it, that's number one down.

However, a PC getting his grubby mitts on a magic item way beyond Table 5-1: Character Wealth by Level (*DMG* 135) is something that must be done at the gaming table or—more likely—written into the background of an already high-level constructed character. If everyone at the table is level 1 and intent on exploring the dungeon and murdering kobolds while one PC wants to find the druid circle so he can borrow their *skin of Kaletor* (see below), chances are not all of the players are on the [same page](https://bankuei.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/the-same-page-tool/), and that's usually a bad thing. But if *everyone* is going a similar wacky, obscure route to achieve maximum power early because it's an extremely high op campaign setting (e.g. the [Tippyverse](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?222007-The-Definitive-Guide-to-the-Tippyverse-By-Emperor-Tippy)), that's number two down.

Anyway, the requirements for the prestige class master of many forms (*Complete Adventurer* 58-60) are the feat [Alertness](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#alertness) (*PH* 89), the feat [Endurance](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#endurance) (*PH* 93), and the class feature [wild shape](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#wildShape). Any level 1 human or a level 1 wizard of any race with a nearby familiar can meet the first two requirements, but the wild shape requirement was obviously put there to delay entry into master of many forms until level 5. The *Dragon* #324 Magic Shop column "Power at a Price," however, introduces

> ### *The Skin of Kaletor*
>
> [...] This bearskin cloak... gives off a powerful rotting stench that is immediately noticeable and incurs a −6 penalty on all Charisma-based skill checks and wild empathy checks.<sup>1</sup> When wearing a *skin of Kaletor*, a druid can use the wild shape ability as if he were four levels higher than his current druid level. Additionally, any non-druid who wears the cloak can use the wild shape ability once per day as a 4th-level druid.<sup>2</sup>
>
> Faint transmutation; CL 4th; [Craft Wondrous Item](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/feats.htm#craftWondrousItem), creator must be a [druid](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm); Price 12,000 gp; Weight 10 lb.

(So we're all on the same page, in my head I've been pronouncing this [KAYL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kale)-tor.)

(There's an argument to be made that a Drd1 gets nothing from the *skin*, as he does *not* have the class feature wild shape and *is* a a druid, but I find it unlikely that *this* is the argument that stops the character from doing what he wants.)

Anyway, assuming pure theorycraft or the DM's a goldfish or the player's persuasive powers are *amazing* or everyone in the group doing likewise, a Drd1 who borrows an [*ioun stone*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/wondrousItems.htm#iounStones) (dark blue rhomboid) (*DMG* 260) (10,000 gp; 0 lbs.) to get the feat Alertness and *Shadahkar's swift wind* (*Dragon* #324 75-6) (8,350 gp; 1 lb.) to get the feat Endurance<sup>3</sup> and a *skin of Kaletor* to get the special ability wild shape **and** who employs all 3 items while advancing a level (see Experience and Levels on *PH* 58-9) can take as his second character level the first level of the prestige class master of many forms.

This is, in case this isn't clear enough already, utterly crazy.

It is the subject of [some](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/38161/8610) [debate](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/41888/8610) whether the druid must *keep* these items (or, y'know, find *another* way of meeting the master of many forms requirements) *either* to continue advancing in the prestige class master of many forms *or* to use any abilities of the prestige class master of many forms. Especially as, after returning the *skin* to its rightful owner, the DM must determine whether the additional uses per day of the special ability wild shape granted by the master of many forms add to the creature's zero wild shape uses per day (therefore allowing the creature to wild shape 1/day as a Drd1/Master of Many Forms 1) or to the creature's Ø wild shape uses per day (therefore allowing the creature to wild shape... um... Ø/day). But, y'know, if things have gone *this* far without the DM objecting, I can't see *this* as the problem.

#### Campaign Ramifications

A campaign in which any Drd1 could take the prestige class master of many forms at level 2 is a scary one. Changing form is one of the most awesome and game-breaking special abilities in *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*—on par with (and slightly off to the side of) spells and psionic powers—, and being able to do so to the degree the master of many forms does at such an early level creates a campaign world that's potentially *terrifying*. Druids are already the game's most powerful base class; this campaign world is likely ruled by them. I mean, even more than most campaign worlds are.

---

#### Notes

<sup>**1**</sup> I'm not sure why it matters how things react to the *skin*—it's not described as usually an [intelligent item](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/intelligentItems.htm), and the skin certainly doesn't have the special ability wild empathy. (I know, article author Robert J. Hahn, that this is the editor's fault—I'm just messin' with you.)
<sup>**2**</sup> Which is hilarious, as a level 4 druid doesn't possess the supernatural ability wild shape. (I figure this is *also* the editor's fault.)
<sup>**3**</sup> Yes, the *same* article. I *know*.