# Which, if any, parts of the Locate City Bomb are dubious by RAW?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, optimization

The “*locate city* bomb” is a somewhat-notorious example of theoretical optimization, turning a minor 1st-level divination into something quite similar to a nuclear blast that kills everything for miles around.

The typical process:

Typical process:

> 1. Cast *locate city* from *Races of Destiny*.
> 2. Use the Snowcasting feat from *Frostburn* to add the Cold descriptor to *locate city*.
> 3. Use the Flash Frost feat from *Player’s Handbook II*, which can only be applied to cold spells, to add 2 cold damage to all creatures within the area of the Snowcasted *locate city*.
> 4. Use the Energy Substitution feat from *Complete Arcane*, which can only be applied to a spell that have the acid, cold, electricity, or fire descriptor, to turn the cold damage to electricity damage, and change the descriptor to the corresponding one.
> 5. Use the Born of the Three Thunders feat from *Complete Arcane*, which can only be applied to an area spell with the electricity or sonic descriptor that deals hit point damage. Among other things, this forces creatures within *locate city*’s area to make a Reflex save.
> 6. Use the Explosive Spell feat from *Complete Arcane*, which can only be applied to a cone-, cylinder-, line-, or burst-area spell that allows a Reflex save, to force those within who fail the Reflex save to the edge of the effect, taking 1d6 damage for every 10 feet moved.

Which, if any, of these steps are dubious per [the rules as written](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/104165/4563)?

Comment: What prompted this?

Comment: @fectin-freeMonica It’s a common enough point of contention, but the proximate cause was [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/159378/4563).

Comment: Are we certain this isn't a duplicate? I'm sure that I've seen this elsewhere. Admittedly, searching "Locate City" on the 3.5e tag doesn't bring up any obvious dupes.

Comment: @J.Mini On this site? I’m about 90% sure not. I did double-check, though it’s of course possible that I misremembered and also missed it in my search query. But I suspect you are thinking of a similar discussion on another site, since this is an argument that comes up from time to time. Or perhaps you’re thinking about one of the other questions about *locate city* where it was argued in comments or perhaps within an answer, but as a tangent, not the actual question.

Comment: @J.Mini You may be thinking of [this answer] that describes the spell bomb's game mechanics, likening it to a small (for some definitions of *small*) nuclear weapon.

Comment: @HeyICanChan You forgot the actual URL part of your hyperlink ;)

Comment: Darn it. [Here.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/94823/8610)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

## The trick's limited to casters that don't prepare spells

Not dubious and more just not mentioned is that access to the *locate city* bomb is incredibly limited. Only casters who cast spells without preparation can drop a *locate city* bomb, and a *locate city* bomb can't be brewed into a potion, scribed onto a scroll, or put into a wand. That said, if the reader is unsurprised to learn that the *locate city* bomb is the exclusive province of characters *both* that are mid-level bards, sorcerers, and other casters that don't prepare spells *and* that have access to either the bard, sorcerer, or ranger spell list, then the reader should skip to this answer's Issues section.

The *locate city* bomb the question describes requires that the 1st-level Sor/Wiz spell ***locate city*** [div] (*Races of Destiny* 166) be modified by the metamagic feat **Flash Frost Spell** (*Player's Handbook II* 91). That metamagic feat can be applied "only to spells that have the cold descriptor." When it's prepared, the spell *locate city* doesn't have the descriptor cold, and it won't gain that descriptor until *after* to it has been applied the benefit of the general feat **Snowcasting** (*Frostburn* 50), and that feat's benefit applies when the spell's *cast* not *prepared*.

Thus the typical prepared caster can't prepare a *flash frost locate city* spell. (If he could, the spell would typically occupy a 2nd-level spell slot as the "flash frost spell uses up a spell slot one level higher than the spell’s actual level.") By extension this means that the typical prepared caster also can't prepare the *locate city* spell modified by the metamagic feats **Born of the Three Thunders** (*Complete Arcane* 76), **Energy Substitution** (electricity) (*Shadowdale: Scouring of the Land* 149), and **Explosive Spell** (*CAr* 79) so as to make a (potential) bomb. (If a typical prepared caster like a ranger or wizard could prepare in one of his spell slots a *locate city* bomb, the *born of the three thunders explosive energy substitution* (electricity) *flash frost locate city* spell would occupy a 4th-level spell slot, so you know.)

In fact, it seems that of the core classes only bards and sorcerers can cast the *locate city* bomb as the question describes. The bard or sorcerer takes a move action to collect some nearby snow and takes 1 round (the *locate city* spell's normal casting time) then 1 full-round action (the extra time a caster that doesn't prepare spells needs to apply one or more metamagic feats' benefits to a spell) to employ the feat Snowcasting while casting the *locate city* spell modified by the feats Born of the Three Thunders, Energy Substitution (electricity), Explosive Spell, and Flash Frost Spell, the (heavily) modified spell expending one of that sorcerer or bard's precious 4th-level spell slots.

To be clear, at its most basic, this means that a *locate city* bomb comes from at least a bard 10 (about 1/day) or sorcerer 8 (about 3/day). Also, since neither class receives bonus feats, the trick's game elements marshal every level-up feat the character gained during levels 1–7 plus maybe another feat in the feat **Eschew Materials** (*Player's Handbook* 94) as this selection of feats is generally suboptimal if the Snowcasting feat goes unused (see also [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/159260/8610)). If the bomb—for whatever reason—does *not* work, that's *a lot* of wasted effort and resources.

### Issues—dubious and otherwise

Below are this writer's immediate concerns with the process the question proposes.

- **Does the *perfect* flash frost spell even exist?** The Flash Frost Spell feat in isolation from a rules-as-written perspective is *at least* mildly dysfunctional. The benefit of the feat Flash Frost Spell "can be applied only to spells… that affect an area" and a spell so modified "deals an extra 2 points of cold damage per level of the spell to all targets in the area" (*PH2* 91). Most spells that have an [area](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#area) entry don't also have a [target or targets](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#target-or-targets) entry. None of the spells in the *Player's Handbook* have both, for example. (While the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*shatter*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#shatter) [trans] (*PH* 278) and the 3rd-level druid spell [*quench*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#quench) [trans] (*PH* 267–8) both offer the caster a choice between *either* an area *or* a target, neither spell has a mode that offers *both* an area *and* one or more targets.) Given the game's vastness, there's probably a spell that the feat Flash Frost Spell as written *can* modify, but finding such a spell won't be effortless, and the spell *locate city* won't be among them.

  It's entirely possible, however, to read the benefit of the Flash Frost Spell feat's use of the word *target* as informal, but then what *is* dealt damage when the feat's applied to the *locate city* spell? Were a spell that normally deals damage modified by the feat, a reader could discern these informal targets, but as the *locate city* spell doesn't normally deal damage, the DM must rule what these informal targets are. Any creature in the area? All creature and unattended objects in the area? All creatures, their attended objects, and unattended objects in the area? And so on. The question asks what parts of the *locate city* bomb need DM adjudication, and this *is* a point that the DM must address as the Flash Frost Spell feat provides no guidance in this regard.
- **What does *extra* mean?** The spell modified by the feat Flash Frost Spell "deals an extra 2 points of cold damage per level of the spell" (*PH2* 91). There is no formal definition of *extra damage* when the term is used in this fashion. (The *Rules Compendium*, for example, consistently uses the term almost exclusively in conjunction with critical hits, a nonstarter here.)

  This makes it unclear if a *flash frost locate city* spell deals 2 points of damage because the extra damage applies *despite* the underlying spell dealing no damage *or* deals no damage precisely *because* the underlying spell deals no damage. There is, so far as I can tell, no textual support for ∅+X=X besides—and I don't use the term pejoratively—common sense (i.e. adding something to nothing nets something). However, as this is a role-playing, a case can be made for ∅+X=∅. This'll take a minute.

  The *Dungeon Master's Guide* on Effect of Weapon Size that says, "Weapons that deal less than 1 point of damage have no effect. Once a weapon only deals 1 point of damage, it’s not a weapon if it shrinks further" (28). Thus, for example, a [grig](http://dndsrd.net/monstersS.html#grig) ninja can only look forlornly at its sized-for-a-Tiny-creature poisoned *+1 [flaming](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#flaming) shuriken* (*PH* 117, 121) (166 gp 1 sp; 0.025 lbs.). The object, although crafted as a weapon (so it also can't be used instead as an [improvised weapon](http://dndsrd.net/weapons.html#improvised-weapons)), is—according to the *DMG*—just not a weapon, and it has no effect. Even were the grig to somehow make an attack with it, no effect—in this DM's opinion—includes things like the ninja's extraordinary ability sudden strike, any poison coating the shuriken, and the magic weapon special ability *flaming*. Another reader's opinion on the definition of *no effect* may vary, of course, but I suspect that a DM that tells a player that a monster's attack had no effect then goes on to detail how the PC has been poisoned, level drained, and improved grabbed will be seen as a bit disingenuous.

  The wider view is this: If X can't do Y, then doing Y with X anyway also can't result in Z. For example, when a *flash frost locate city* spell is cast, because the spell normally doesn't deal any damage, the spell's effect won't generate other effects that're contingent upon the spell dealing damage. Those are just ignored.

  In sum, to this reader, saying that the extra damage from the Flash Frost Spell feat applies to the spell *locate city* is like asking Pizza Hut to deliver a topping but no pizza: Chances are an intrepid negotiator *could* buy from a Pizza Hut *only* a topping just like a determined player *could* find a DM who'd agree that the +2 points of extra cold damage from the feat Flash Frost Spell can be added to the *locate city* spell's ∅ damage, but she might have to shop around for an accommodating Pizza Hut or an agreeable DM.
- **How do metamagic benefits apply exactly?** As previously discussed, there's an absolutely precise order of operations that *must* be adhered to if a *locate city* bomb is to be dropped. After realizing the benefit of the feat Snowcasting the caster of the spell *locate city* then applies on the fly to that spell the following metamagic feats in this exact order: first, the feat Flash Frost Spell that can only be applied to spells that possess the descriptor cold; second, the feat Energy Substitution (electricity) that changes the *locate city* spell's descriptor from cold to electricity; third, the feat Born of the Three Thunders that can only be applied to a spell that deals electricity or sonic damage and that adds an effect requiring a Reflex saving throw; and, fourth, the feat Explosive Spell that can only be applied to a spell that mandates a Reflex saving throw. If metamagic feats are applied *in any other order* the bomb is a dud.

  This reader agrees with [this fine answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/159394/8610) that constant targeting isn't a thing in *D&D 3.5.* (Also see [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/142274/8610); I mean, I, like, *really* agree!) However, when metamagic is applied to a spell, it's unclear if the metamagic benefits apply sequentially in the order the caster prefers or if the benefits apply simultaneously.

  In a totally different context, the [sometimes-suspect](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60044/8610) *Main FAQ* says that as "a general guideline, whenever the rules don’t stipulate an order of operations… apply them in the order that’s most beneficial to the 'controller' of the effect" (51), but this general guideline is *not* followed by the only example of the interaction between metamagic feats when their order application matters: the interaction between the feats [**Empower Spell**](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#empower-spell) (*PH* 93) and [**Maximize Spell**](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#maximize-spell) (97–8). The printed benefit of the feat Maximize Spell, in part, says

  > An empowered, maximized spell gains the separate benefits of each feat: the maximum result plus one-half the normally rolled result. An empowered, maximized *fireball* cast by a 15th-level wizard deals points of damage equal to 60 plus one half of 10d6. (*ibid.*)

  To my knowledge, no other examples exist of how to apply metamagic benefits when the order is actually important, as it is to make a *locate city* bomb. In other words, for a *locate city* bomb to go off, the DM *must* rule that each metamagic feat is applied in the most favorable order.

  If the DM rules that each metamagic feat is applied simultaneously and separately, then the feats Flash Frost Spell and feat Energy Substitution (electricity) find the spell *locate city* with its descriptor cold from the Snowcasting feat acceptable, but the feats Born of the Three Thunders and Explosive Spell do *not* find the cold *locate city* spell acceptable: the cold *locate city* spell won't be eligible for those feats until *after* the other feats have been applied to the spell.

  In short, this is a gray area as there is no rule-as-written order of metamagic benefits application—and the DM *must* rule that order of application favors the bomber for the *locate city* bomb to work. This general topic, by the way, is rarely broached. I found only a [2013 thread](http://www.ruleofcool.com/smf/index.php/topic,670.0.html) from the *Rule of Cool* messageboards that reaches some eyebrow-raising conclusions in support of simultaneity and a [2005 thread](https://www.tapatalk.com/groups/gameschat19968/application-of-multiple-metamagic-feats-t1974.html) from Andy Collins's  *Tapatalk* messageboards. (Unfortunately, *3.5* revision architect Collins himself doesn't participate in the latter, but the OP of the former does—in 2013! Small world.)

  (So the reader's aware, besides the *locate city* bomb the other topic in metamagic application ambiguity is the duration of a spell modified by *both* the feat [**Extend Spell**](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#extend-spell) (*PH* 94) *and* the feat **Persistent Spell** (*CAr* 81). Folks apparently die on hills named 24 Hours, 24 Hours Plus Its Normal Duration, 48 Hours, and Would You Guys Keep It Down? We're Trying to Play a Game Here.)
- **A circle is a burst?** Although he knows he shouldn't be, this reader actually *is* mildly uncomfortable with the *locate city* spell's entry *Area: 10 miles/level radius circle, centered on you* meeting the requirement of the feat Explosive Spell that says that the feat's benefit "can be applied only to spells that… affect an area (a cone, cylinder, line, or burst)" (79). The entry *10 miles/level radius circle, centered on you* is an *Other* area about which that the *Player's Handbook* says, "A spell can have a unique area, as defined in its description" (*PH* 176). Like the 2nd-level Sor/Wiz spell [***locate object***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsHtoL.html#locate-object) [div] (249) and its entry *Area: Circle, centered on you, with a radius of 400 ft. + 40 ft./level* and the 6th-level Sor/Wiz [***control weather***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsC.html#control-weather) [trans] (214) and its entry *Area: 2-mile-radius circle, centered on you; see text*, the spell *locate city* just doesn't have an area that's a cone, cylinder, line, or burst.

  Technically, it seems that the *locate city* spell is ineligible on these grounds alone to be the beneficiary of the feat Explosive Spell. (Ironically, as this [fine answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/159394/8610) mentions, equally ineligible is the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*fireball*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsFtoG.html#fireball) [evoc] (231) that has the entry  *Area: 20-ft.-radius spread* and that has the fact that it's a darn spread mentioned *in the example* in the benefit of the feat Explosive spell! [*Cue groans.*])
- **"Mission Control, am I ready for launch?"** This isn't dubious *per se*, but it is something to be aware of. The spell *locate city* possesses the entries *Range: 10 miles/level* and *Area: 10 miles/level radius circle, centered on you*. Unlike a normal area spell that has its casters "select the point [within the spell's *range* entry] where the spell originates" (*PH* 175), the caster is *always* the center of the *locate city* effect. This may mean that, if a caster *does* manage to drop a *locate city* bomb, she herself may need a way to avoid the ensuing effect. (The game tends to say so when an effect is centered on the caster yet leaves the caster unaffected; cf. the safe-for-the-caster 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell *fireburst* [evoc] (*SpC* 93) *et al.* and the your-psion-has-acid-resistance-right? 6th-level psion/wilder power [*breath of the black dragon*](http://dndsrd.net/psionicPowersAtoC.html#breath-of-the-black-dragon) [psychometabolism] (*Expanded Psionics Handbook* 81).)

  In other words, a DM that sees a Sor8 drop a *locate city* bomb may rule that the caster rockets straight up, is dealt 42,240d6 points of damage, and is technically in space. (Also see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/31745/8610).)

I know that's a lot, but there's a lot here to unpack. Your patience is appreciated. Anyway, to sum up, there are, in my opinion, a few dubious points according to the rules as written, therefore making it so the DM must rule on the following points:

1. Can the benefit of the Flash Frost Spell feat be applied to spells that possess an area entry yet that don't also possess a target entry?
2. When a spell benefits from the feat Flash Frost Spell, is the damage that's a benefit of the feat dealt no matter the spell's normal effect?
3. Are metamagic benefits applied sequentially in the order the recipient chooses?
4. When the game uses the word *circle*, does it actually mean *sphere*, and is that sphere also a burst?

If to each of those questions you said *Yes*, then you can drop a *locate city* bomb as the question describes. However, then the DM must answer the final question: *Will the caster be affected by the spell?*

---

***Note:*** Even if the DM says yes to only #1 and #2, a Sor4 with a Snowcast flash frost locate city *spell can take 1 round then a full round action to commit murder on a kingdom scale. Just sayin'. Also I have come to hate the feat Explosive Spell. Seriously, no damage cap? Really?*

Comment: I can't downvote such a good answer over it, but so far as I can tell, there is absolutely no reason whatsoever to suspect that any and all uses of the word “target” solely and exclusively refer to the “Target” entry of a spell, and I find the suggestion that it does here problematic and misleading.

Comment: @KRyan I hope the answer now addresses your concerns.

Comment: Yup, that’s a fair point there and this answer is excellent.

Comment: +1 because I strongly approve of this answer confirming my feelings about 3.5 some 10+ years ago despite what everyone on the PbP board I was on.

Comment: I'll point out that it's possible for the caster to avoid becoming the test pilot for the Faerunian Space Program simply by casting the spell indoors. If they do want to go to space, though, they can do so simply by chugging a potion of Delay Death and a potion of Beastland Ferocity first, and having a Necklace of Adaptation on them. They get launched into space, get reduced to -150,000hp, and Delay Death prevents them from dying. Then, they start suffocating (because they just got launched into space), and their HP gets set to -1, and they put on their necklace then chug a healing potion.

Comment: @nick012000 The *potion of delay death* may be tough to find in some settings as a 4th-level spell in a potion, but, certainly, the explosive travel that's possibly the result of the *locate city* bomb effect can be survived. (Also see [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/63844/8610).)

Answer (score 15):

RAW, the legality of the *locate city* bomb is ambiguous. Step 3. is the primary problem, hinging on the definition of “extra” which the rules don’t actually define. Step 3. has another possible issue, and step 6. has some maybe-issues, but those I don’t consider those RAW-valid.

1. No problem; clearly *locate city* is a spell that can be cast.
2. No problem; even if you argue that you need to actually have snow around you and use a move action to collect it, you can do that.
3. The Flash Frost feat describes its effect as referring to “spells that use cold and ice to damage your foes.” The problem with this argument, however, is that this is the description, prior to the actual **Benefit** section describing, in rules terms, what the effect is. The benefit section says only that “This metamagic feat can be applied only to spells that have the cold descriptor and that affect an area.” *Locate city* meets those criteria when cast with Snowcasting.

   The benefits section does say that the spell deals “an **extra** 2 points of cold damage,” which is a fairly-common ambiguity in the rules: can you add to, gain a bonus to, gain extra of, something you didn’t have before? Should we treat the spell as having previously done 0 damage, so now it deals 0 + 2 damage, or should we treat “extra” as requiring the damage to have already been present? This is ambiguous. However, “ambiguous” is as far as it goes—the rules use “extra” a lot, and it’s often unclear, but the game never defines it. So this still *could* work. And ruling “extra” as always requiring some previous quantity could set a problematic precedent for a lot of other things, since the word is used a lot.

   Another potential issue for Flash Frost is that we are going to be using Energy Substitution on it to change the cold descriptor, as required by Flash Frost, to the electricity descriptor. However, there really is nothing in the rules that suggests that D&D 3.5e uses “constant targeting,” that would cause us to go back and check the spell’s cold descriptor for Flash Frost after we apply it. What little we do have suggests D&D does not do this. See [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/154345/4563) for more.
4. No problem; with Snowcasting and Flash Frost, *locate city* is a divination [cold] spell that deals 2 cold damage, which Energy Substitution can change to a divination [electricity] spell that deals 2 electricity damage.

   Note that the *Deities & Demigods* version of Energy Substitution, which is also the version found in the SRD, is the older version of the feat, and does not mention changing the descriptors, which would cause a problematic ambiguity. *Complete Arcane* has the latest version of the feat, however, and explicitly addresses this.
5. No problem; *locate city* affects an area, and thanks to the previous steps, ours deals damage and has the electricity descriptor. Works as written.
6. *Locate city* specifies its area as a 10-mile/level-radius circle, and “circle” isn’t on the list of valid area types for Explosive Spell. However, this is really part of a wider underspecification in D&D 3.5e—very few spells actually define themselves to be “bursts” as Explosive Spell indicates. Burst is simply the default kind of area, so things will just say “*X*-foot radius” rather than “*X*-foot-radius burst.” For that matter, they also will often not bother to distinguish between a burst and an emanation—unless the effect moves, the two are usually indistinguishable. Barring Explosive Spell on *locate city* under this rationale would suggest that it also doesn’t apply to a whole host of spells it almost-certainly was intended for—like the *fireball* described in the feat’s own example.

   The other argument people sometimes make is that *locate city* specifies “circle,” rather than “sphere.” The idea isn’t that this prevents the combination, so much as makes it much less useful, as it can only hit things in one plane (the geometric term, not the cosmological one), and even then they’re just shunted above or below that and almost-certainly take no damage as they don’t move 10 feet. This is, in my opinion, truly grasping at straws, and a very bad precedent to set in the game. For one thing, it’s going to cause a lot of problems with using *locate city* for its straightforward purpose, locating cities, but more importantly, the game uses “square” **everywhere** when really it ought to be using “cube.” A whole lot of the game’s rules are written assuming 2D when things are really 3D; who knows why. But *locate city* is just another case of that—trying to argue more than that is just asking for trouble from other precedents.

Note that, regardless of RAW, **I recommend banning the combo.** It’s overpowered. That’s not the question here. Personally, I would probably nix Flash Frost from adding cold damage to any overly-large-area, non-damaging spell. I’d even allow Flash Frost on non-damage spells, so long as they’re small-ish, but not to something so large. Even without the rest, that would cause problems.

Comment: On #3, my concern is that the benefit of the feat Flash Frost Spell says, in part, that a modified "spell deals an *extra* 2 points of cold damage per level of the spell to all targets in the area" (*PH2* 91 and emphasis mine). Since the spell *locate city*, by default, deals not zero but *no* damage then there's nothing delivering that extra 2 points of damage (maybe like somehow applying the *flaming* magic weapon special ability to a sock or some other can't-be-used-as-an-improvised-weapon object). Or is such an avenue simply not worth exploring?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Good point, should address. It’s ambiguous.

Comment: (So far as I can tell, extra damage is pretty consistently used tightly in conjunction with effects that already deal damage. That is, I couldn't quickly find anywhere else where the reader would reach the conclusion that an instance of extra damage can be added to a ∅ quantity. After all, a grig ninja's shuriken deals no damage so he doesn't still deal his sudden strike damage with his shuriken. But you've addressed it, that's cool, and thank you. If I feel strongly about it later, I'll answer the question myself.)

Comment: @HeyICanChan An example like that is precisely what I had in mind. Sudden strike, IIRC, says that if damage is reduced to 0 *by damage reduction* that it doesn’t apply, but this is a weapon that deals \$0\$ damage by default—it’s not clear to me that it shouldn’t be \$0+X\text{d}6\$.

Comment: Actually, the *DMG* says, "Weapons that deal less than 1 point of damage have no effect" (*PH* 28). To me, *no effect* means *as if nothing happened,* but I can understand a *no effect* argument like *the weapon does nothing but my class features and the magic weapon special abilities still work*. However, I wouldn't bet so hard on that being a standard reading that I'd bring a grig ninja with a bunch of *+1 flaming shuriken* to a table without asking first!

Comment: (Not my downvote, by the way. In fact, I upvoted it for addressing my concern.)

Comment: On #3 again: The Benefit section takes precedence when the short description in the beginning of the feats chapter disagrees. But I can find no disagreement here. So the short description shouldn´t be neglected.

Comment: @PeregrinTook The short description has zero rules weight of any kind whatsoever. And there *is* disagreement—a requirement not mentioned is a requirement that doesn’t exist, and having a requirement where the primary source has none is a contradiction, decided in the primary source’s favor.

Comment: Sometimes that short description is the *only* place some rules can be found (as per answers to this [question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/66871/8610)), and, for spells, the short list description is the only place that has a superscript indicating some focus or material components that don't have prices also aren't in a spell component pouch (e.g. *plane shift*, *simulacrum*). Just sayin'.

Comment: @KRyan I found point 3 intriguing. So I asked a [question about it](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/159457/47190)

Answer (score 4):

Snowcasting works fine. it can give any spell a cold descriptor. yay.

The problem is the next step.

Flash frost can't be applied to locate city, because it doesn't affect an area. Having an area, and affecting an area are not the same thing.

"This metamagic feat can be applied only to spells that have the cold descriptor and that ***affect an area***."  RAW.

It reveals the directions to the nearest city, but doesn't actually affect the area.  It just SCANS it.  It affects you, by granting you knowledge, like a divination spell is supposed to.

Thus the whole thing falls apart right there.  Without making Locate City deal damage by using Flash Frost, the other tricks don't work.  You can't use energy substitution or admixture to add in lightning, therefore you can't use born of three thunders to give it a reflex save, therefore you can't apply explosive spell to it.

Comment: RE: "Having an area, and affecting an area are not the same thing." They actually are the same thing if we're talking about a spell's header information: Aiming a Spell on [**Area**](http://dndsrd.net/magicOverview.html#area) begins its description of spells with an Area entry with, "Some spells affect an area." And the *locate city* spell has an Area entry in its header material.

Comment: …And, as if that weren't abrupt enough, welcome to the site! Take the [tour]! It's always good to have another *3.5* voice around these parts. Have fun, and thank you for helping strangers!

Comment: Even if we accept the nonsensical statement that affect an area means the same thing as has an area, Locate City doesn't target.

Implicit targeting (which is what would allow the damage) is tied to the burst, emanation and spread mechanics, and to the Cone, Cylinder, Line, or Sphere shapes.

Unique areas don't do this. They instead work as the spell description says.  

Since 10 miles per level radius circle centered on you is not a burst, spread or emanation, and is not a line, cone, cylinder, or sphere, it is a unique area.

No targets, no damage.  Still doesn't work.

Comment: Nonsensical? Sure, but also the rules. `:-)` I mean, we literally *can't know* what the magic of the *locate city* spell *is*, so it could be sending out a wave of city-searching power (or something) so that the "area" is "affected." As it stands, this answer sounds like it would have DMs determine for each area spell if the spell *really* affects an area like the rules say it does or if the spell's an exception based on the DM's interpretation/understanding of the spell's narrative. That's a big ask.

Comment: Flash frost does add to cone of cold damage, because the damage mechanic in the spell carries an implicit target.  The extra damage semantics don't even matter. Locate city doesn't have this implicit targeting.  The only person it could possibly deal damage to by any stretch is the caster, which is arguably a target of the spell.  And you would still need to rule that it's a cylinder or sphere, and not a circle to get it to even fling you. Which you don't have to do to make Locate City work. It works as it says it does, because it's a unique area.

Comment: The spell places a gps route into your head. :) Could it be any more obvious?

Emanations, bursts, and spreads affect the area like their descriptions in the general rules say. If those aren't present, then spell affects the area in the way the spell says they do.  Simple.  Clear.  

Bursts, emanations, and spreads can deal damage with flash frost. divination spells are rarely one of those.  lines, cones, cylinders, and spheres with indiscriminate effects can deal damage with flash frost.  Locate city isn't any of those.  Unique areas ARE already exceptions to the usual area rules.

Comment: The rules don't mention anything about implied targets, but for spells to even work as written, it seems they do have to be there.  But there isn't any implied targets beyond yourself.  While the 3.5 rules do define settlement types in terms of population ranges, the spell does not specify how it gets that information.  It could read the town records.  Saying that the spell must target every human in it's area to function, and therefore damage from flash frost applies is peasant railgun level deliberate distortion.

Comment: I agree with you on the targeting thing — search this page for *Does the perfect flash frost spell even exist?* — but this answer doesn't mention that. Instead, this answer says that a spell *having* an area is different from a spell *affecting* an area when the rules do actually say that a spell that has an Area entry affects the area. To be clear, I like your take on this issue in these comments (which, in sum, I think is, "The only target *locate city* has is the caster") more than I like the current answer, but it's helped others, so what do I know? `:-)` (BTW, the downvote isn't mine.)

Comment: I have read the area you linked thoroughly.

Some spells affect an area.
Some spells have an area line in the description.
It is stated nowhere that all spells that have an area line affect an area.
It is the descriptions of the standard area types themselves that state this.
This does not apply to unique areas.
It does not logically follow that a spell that has a unique area affects the area.

Yes this is nitpicking.  Such is common with dealing with RAW.