# Can you take a second real level of Ur-Priest?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, prestige-class

Ur-priest has as a prerequisite an inability to cast divine spells.  It also grants divine spells.  The first level's fine, because you don't necessarily have spells yet, but every level after that the class would seem to interfere with its own progression.  Is there some rule that resolves this issue?

I'm aware that there are lots of other ways to level up a class other than actually putting levels in it, but this is about doing it the 'normal' way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can by RAW take a second level in Ur-Priest. The requirement of not being able to cast divine spells is a requirement "to **become** an ur-priest". It is not a prerequisite for taking levels in the prestige class, only for taking the prestige class in the first place.

Comment: Technically, the *Dungeon Master’s Guide* states that this is true of **all** requirements for **all** prestige classes: requirements must be met in order to take your first level. Beyond that, according to the DMG, all bets are off.

Comment: @KRyan True. But though I personally feel the DMG is clear enough on this under an impartial reading, the wording is insufficiently emphatic to resist determined rules-lawyering (or to make for a pithy quote).

Comment: Strangely enough, it is those who insist on the DMG’s rules who are accused of rules-lawyering, and the (factually inaccurate) [answer here contradicting the DMG](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/41895/4563) is highest-rated and accepted. You are right that *Complete Divine* is solid on this point though, either way.

Comment: @KRyan Rules might simply be getting lawyered in whichever direction the desired outcome lies at the moment, like the Sophists and modern attorneys.