# What is the ending type and subtype of this creature?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, forgotten-realms

*Note: For the following question, I will use the convention of noting creature type with [brackets] and placing creature sub-type(s) within (parentheses).*

A chaotic evil fire elf<sup>1</sup> (UA, p. 17) Cleric of Cyric 11/Divine Disciple 4 of Cyric who has ascended to lichdom (MM, p. 166; Monsters of Faerun, p. 89) is about to take her final level of the Divine Disciple prestige class (PGtF, p. 51).

At ECL 19, her type and subtype tags ought be:

> [Undead] (Augmented Humanoid) (Elf) (Fire)

When she takes her 5th level of Divine Disciple, the class ability "*Transcendence*" will attempt to change her type and subtype(s) to the following:

> [Outsider] (Native) (Augmented Undead) (Augmented Humanoid) (Elf) (Fire) (Chaotic) (Evil)

However, I seem to recall a specific bit of text regarding the Undead type being an "end-state" creature type. I am unable to find this rule or parsing of text, and so I am unsure if I am incorrect. If such a rule *does* exist, can someone please remind me of where to find it? I strongly believed it was in *Savage Species*, but my inability to find this rule within that book leads me to believe I was erroneous regarding such a rule.

If such a rule *does* exist, how does that effect the Cleric/Divine Disciple?

Would it be closer to the following:

> [Undead] (Augmented Outsider) (Native) (Augmented Humanoid) (Elf) (Fire)(Chaotic) (Evil)

I understand that the question might seem to be a bit hair-splitting, but as this creature will form the central antagonist to a high level party, I want to insure I am getting the typing and sub-typing correct.

Clarification: For the purpose of helping potential answers, I am concerned with this from a rules-as-written perspective not because I just want to "see what happens" when this character reaches 20th level, but because I want to see if she actually becomes less difficult to combat if "*Transcendence*" changes her type again.

I am more concerned with making a rules-correct choice that is *more challenging* for the party than a rules-correct choice that is *more interesting* to the party.

<sup>1</sup>: <sup>While fire elves, and many of the other variants of races found within *Unearthed Arcana*, are not included in the races of the *Forgotten Realms*, this campaign does use the racial variants rules found in *Unearthed Arcana*.</sup>

Comment: [This bit of craziness may help.](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/65299/8610)

Comment: Is this a for-reals, Ima-gonna-make-this-here-nutty-PC-for-a-campaign question, or are you, instead, curious generally about what occurs when a creature's type changes multiple times to seemingly incompatible possibilities?

Comment: @HeyICanChan - This creature is planned as a (hopefully) properly difficult "BBEG" to antagonize the party. While the issues of typing and subtyping are a general curiosity as well, I do need to know which outcome is more correct for issues regarding this character's HP, resistances, immunities, bonuses, and so forth. Thank you for linking your answer,  you've already helped me find the text from *SS* which I missed. . . Though I am not sure if that "Type Pyramid" is as helpful as I was hoping.

Comment: The type pyramid is, was, and will be an ugly, tacked-on mistake. *Please* don't try to use it, and try to forget it exists, a miserable remnant of the game *Savage Species* never was.

Comment: Hair-splitting is something we handle! That's a perfect use of the [[tag:rules-as-written]] tag. :)

Comment: I know this may be a side issue, but this *is* a rules-as-written question: Is there evidence of the existence fire elves in the Forgotten Realms? Or should answers assume such things exist anyway?

Comment: @HeyICanChan - No. Apologies, I should edit that into the question. Because of the many varieties of races in the setting, our table also uses the additional racial variants found in *Unearthed Arcana*, but not already found in the *Forgotten Realms* - to sort of "amp up" the melting pot of diverse variants. It's such a commonly assumed aspect of the world for the table that I had forgotten it is not within the typical scope of the *Forgotten Realms*, apologies.

Comment: Totally cool. I was just assuming that, by default, there're no such thing as fire elves in the Realms. I'm no Realms scholar—for all I know, there are! I was really just wondering if *you* knew. (And it seems you do and there aren't. All good.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## The end type should be Outsider

The final level changes the creature's type to outsider, and from a strict rules-as-written perspective, that's all we need to care about.  Savage species, where the 'type pyramid' is found, doesn't officially have the jurisdiction to impose that pyramid on *The Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting*, *Players Guide to Faerun*, etc, which are all the primary source for their own templates, and the Monster Manual is the primary source for how templates work in general.  So, from a strict rules position, this type pyramid thing doesn't matter.

ALSO the pyramid doesn't matter, because it only governs (or pretends to govern) type changes based on templates, not any other source.  Your 5th level class feature is not a template; the only template used herein is 'Lich'.  So, even if you ignore the primary source rules and use the pyramid, this character is still an outsider.

If you instead wanted the character to be Undead, all you would need to do (regardless of type pyramid nonesense) is change the order in which the things are applied.  Become a Lich *after* taking that last level, and you're Undead instead of Outsider.  This is actually significantly more powerful, because then you are Undead (augmented outsider) instead of Outsider (augmented undead), which nets you the Undead traits with Outsider features (like better skill point stuff) v.s. Outsider traits with Undead features (like terrible BAB and saves coupled with no significant defenses).

---

## Why does it matter if I'm Undead(augmented Outsider) or Outsider(augmented Undead)?  What's the difference?

When you get a template, you gain the augmented subtype, which changes how things work for you a bit:

> A creature with the augmented subtype usually has the traits of its current type, but the features of its original type.

Ok, so nothing is providing exception to this set up in our case, so lets look at what happens:

Undead says some stuff about hp, BAB, saves, and skill points.  Then it says "These are features of the Undead type".  That's how you know that they are features, not traits.  Every type says this, though, and it's always BAB, saves, skill points, and HD size.

It also gives you a *huge* pile of immunities and special things and whatnot, and calls those traits.  Those are the traits, not features, and they vary wildly by type beyond consistently telling you if something eats, breathes, and/or sleeps or not.

If you're an Outsider, but augmented Undead, you *don't* get the Outsider type's 8+int skill points and two free class skills and amazing saves and full BAB, and instead get the Undead type's terrible BAB, Will-only saves, 4+int skills, and its admittedly really-good d12 HD.  You also don't get the Undead type's lack of a Con score, immunity to Fort save effects except ones that kill you dead, immunity to death from massive damage, weird resurrection stuff, being able to run forever without getting tired, etc.  Instead you get proficiency with simple and martial weapons and that's about it.  So one of these is kinda okay and one of them is ridiculously amazing.

Lastly, your type doesn't generally affect your ability to use your stuff unless that stuff depends on type, which the Lich's phylactery doesn't.  Whether you are an Undead (augmented Outsider) or an Outsider (augmented Undead), your phylactery will still work.

While the Undead type has the massive drawback that you die when you are killed, the Outsider type has an only slightly less serious resurrection drawback, so that's not really a power consideration here.

### But Lich takes care of some of that, right?

Yes, it does.  The Lich template sets all current and future HD to d12s, and provides immunity to mind-affecting effects, and removes ones Constitution score.  These things will still happen even if you're not Undead anymore, so long as you're a Lich (unless you get something that specifically changes this, like *Polymorph Any Object* specifying you gain a Con score, or another template changing your HD size again).  It's still not nearly as good, barring very specific build situations, to be an Outsider(augmented Undead) as it is to be Undead(augmented Outsider).  You're still missing out on tons of stuff.

### Can I really even get Undead(augmented Outsider)?  Wouldn't I need to settle for Undead(augmented Humanoid) or Outsider(augmented Undead) instead?

Yup!  While the Lich template can only be applied to humanoids, you can take humanoid form with your 15 levels of Cleric of Cyric spellcasting as *Polymorph Any Object* is an 8th level trickery domain spell.  If you didn't take trickery as one of your Cleric of Cyric domains (for shame!) then you would need a scroll of regular polymorph or similar.  Either way, you can go back to being a humanoid in order to then become a lich and then end the polymorph effect.

Comment: I think the bigger concern, however, is what's lost, gained, lost, then regained by going from humanoid to undead to outsider. That is, does the end creature's phylactery still return it to existence were it destroyed? Similarly, is the end creature, for example, immune to precision damage, mind-affecting effects, and effects that require a Fort save yet don't affect objects?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Oh, ok, I didn't realize that was in the solution domain.  I'll add a section explaining the difference between features and traits.

Comment: (That's my assumption, anyway, based on the asker wanting to "mak[e] a rules-correct choice that is more challenging for the party.")

Comment: @HeyICanChan better?

Comment: @thedarkwanderer - thank you for the answer. I was having some difficulty discerning exactly which conditions precipitated which outcomes. (That is, if the Undead type would be a so-called "end state" type.)
As a final curiosity, though... Even if the creature loses the undead type, she retains d12 hit die progression for her remaining level due to the lich template, correct? If so, does that mean she would regain her CON score at level 20, and also retain her retroactive and future d12 progression?

Comment: Also, for your own edification, you cannot apply the lich template to a creature with the [Outsider] type; the lich template requiring a [Humanoid] type.

Comment: *jurisdiction* really?

Comment: @Wyrmwood you got a better word?

Comment: Not really. We simply have a fundamentally different understanding of the primacy rule.