# Can a drow be persuaded not to be evil?

Tags: alignment

The party encountered a drow. As a joke, my character winked at the drow and flirted with it. The drow walked up to my character and kissed my character on the lips! The DM then decreed that my character and the drow were married! However, the drow remains an evil monster that likes to torture folks, and I'm afraid it might attack the party. Is there a way to persuade the drow not to attack the party, or, better yet, a way to persuade the drow to just *not be evil* anymore?

Comment: Your campaign's tone seems to be rather wacky, so I guess anything goes.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Take the [tour]. Congratulations on your character's nuptials. I've edited your question for clarity; I hope that's okay. The question *desperately* needs to be tagged with a game system; doing so might go a long way toward getting it reopened. Thank you for participating and have fun.

Comment: @Shalvenay Depending on the system, this may be solvable mechanically and needn't be opinion at all, which is why I want a system tag. For instance, [this answer](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/68260/8610) describes several methods that can be used to force a creature to change alignment in *D&D 3.5*. (I do agree, though, that it might behoove the asker to familiarize himself with the [drow portrayal in popular culture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drizzt_Do%27Urden) and be a bit more open-minded.)

Comment: Anything short of "what are rule based ways to force an alignment change" is probably going to still be too subjective, and from the scenario posed does anyone really think hardcode rules wonkery is at play in this campaign?

Comment: If you want to presuade the drow not the be evil, consider if the drow can persuade you to be evil? It all depends on how much she / he loves  you.