# what happens if an anointed knight loses his/her ancestral weapon?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

The situation: the ancestral weapon was destroyed by acid. Does the character lose the prestige class? Is there any way to keep the class or get another weapon?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]. The part about losing prestige class requirements is likely answered by answers to [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/41888/8610), but *How can I regain an ancestral relic?* remains a unique question; editing this question to *only* that question would improve it. Thank you for participating and have fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless a prestige class contains an explicit “Ex” section describing a loss of class features or right to progress the class, it is impossible to lose either per the rules in the *Dungeon Master’s Guide* (see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/41888/4563) for more details, including the possible exceptions for prestige classes in *Complete Arcane* or *Complete Warrior*). So once an anointed knight, always an anointed knight. You do not lose the class features without an ancestral weapon, you just have no ancestral weapon to use some of them on.

Moreover, the Ancestral Relic feat gives you the ability to summon the latent powers of a relic. You still have that ability; it wasn’t specific to the relic that got destroyed. The feat does limit you to awakening a single relic at a time, but since your relic was destroyed, you are now free to awaken a new one. Finding another qualifying item may be difficult, but that can be a fun side-quest for you.