# Improving base Fortitude for early ur-priest entry

Tags: dnd-3.5e, optimization, saving-throw

I am not entirely satisfied by my answers to [Is it possible to achieve 9th level spells in 3 different progressions?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/108182/4563) since one requires treating a divine spellcasting class as arcane by using Alternate Source Spell, an interaction I find dubious by RAW, and the other relies on leveling up during the very short window provided by *divine power* and locks us into divine crusader for one of our progressions.

To get around these issues, I would like to use an arcane base class instead of sublime chord while still using ur-priest rather than divine crusader. In order to accomplish the required triple-9s, that means starting ur-priest at 3rd level. That means by 2nd level, I need a +3 base Fortitude save (and Will save but that part’s easy).

The ideal start to this build is a level in druid and then a level in wizard: that qualifies me for the blighter prestige class, and then allows me to progress wizard up to its 9th-level spells (just barely) by 20th. Sha’ir or wu jen would also work. A class that gets 9th-level spells by 18th level, like beguiler, dread necromancer, sorcerer, or warmage, misses out, but I *could* ditch the druid level and blighter in favor of getting that 18th effective level and using divine crusader instead of blighter.

But the problem is that none of those arcane classes have a good Fort save, so even when I take a level of druid (which does), and even when I use fractional saves, that only gets me to a +2⅚ base Fort bonus, which while frustratingly close to +3, is definitely *not* +3.

So I am looking for one of two things:

- A base class with good Fort and Will saves, and gets 9th-level arcane spells by 18th at the latest. I am almost-certain this doesn’t exist, but it would work.
- Some kind of way to cheese a higher base save bonus than my classes otherwise offer. Since this is in answer to the linked question the same restriction applies:

  > Prestige classes allowed from any 3.5 official publication, including dragon magazine. Assume fractional stat advancement (save, BAB), alignment changes as you see fit,
  >
  > Forbidden: 3.5 FAQ, negative level shedding, pun-pun, DCFS, Unearthed Arcana.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Maho-Tsukai

The maho-tsukai prestige class, from the back of *Oriental Adventures*, is a 15-level full arcane casting class with a unique ability: when you enter the class, you can exchange other spellcasting levels (arcane or divine) for spellcasting levels of this class. It's got a decent enough spell list (similar to core wizard), and a couple other unique class features, but what matters to us is the casting ability. You can start out with duskblade, a good Fort/Will class, and have its casting contribute to your full progression.

Comment: Awesome, +1 and thank you. I think the discussion of how to use it to achieve triple-9s is better as an answer to the other question (though you probably should detail it rather than just linking the spreadsheet; I can help with the table if you like).

Comment: Alright; edited that to just note the spellcasting class details.