# Can spells stolen from a Shadow Weave user be cast by a Knight of the Weave/Spellthief character?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, forgotten-realms

The Knight of the Weave prestige class has an entry requirement that the character cannot be a Shadow Weave user.

I am assuming that this means you cannot have the Shadow Weave Magic feat.

If you also have levels in Spellthief and you manage to steal a spell from a Shadow Weave user as a Knight of the Weave, I would argue that you can cast the stolen spell, because stealing the spell doesn't make you a Shadow Weave user.

My DM is arguing that the spell is "tainted" as it comes from the Shadow Weave, and that as a Knight of the Weave, you are obliged to defend the Weave and therefore can't use the spell that you stole, even if it's to use against the Shadow Weave user.

In this case, do the ends justify the means?

Answer (score 1):

## Its your DM's call.

When the rules are ambiguous, it is up to the DM to adjudicate.

If you disagree with the DM's decision here, you can discuss it with them and try to come to a new agreement about what your class restrictions mean, or ask to be allowed to rebuild if the character you initially envisioned doesn't work under their interpretation of the rules.

### Your DM's decision is well supported by the rules

The prohibition against being a shadow weave user doesn't care how you get your shadow weave magic. If it meant only to ban the Shadow Weave Magic *feat*, it would say so. A someone who uses the shadow weave is a user of the shadow weave, no matter how they got access to it.

The prohibition also doesn't care about who the target of your shadow weave magic is. A reformed shadow weave user turned follower of Mystra who has sworn off the shadow weave magic except when fighting other shadow weave users might well be an interesting character, but that character doesn't qualify for the Knight of the Weave prestige class.

A spellthief who uses stolen shadow weave magic against its original casters is still a shadow weave user - just one who got access to the shadow weave through nonstandard means. Mystra would prefer that those spells not be cast at all.

#### On a technicality, you might be able keep your powers, if your DM accepts it

[Unless otherwise stated, you do not lose access to a prestige class's abilities just by failing to meet its prerequisites](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/41888/do-you-lose-your-prestige-class-features-when-you-no-longer-meet-its-requirement), and indeed, can even continue to take levels in it.

There are no rules that say a Knight of the Weave loses their powers if go against the principles of the class, unlike Paladins, Druids, and many prestige classes from the Book of Exalted Deeds. Thus, RAW technically allows for Knights of the Weave to use their abilities however they like after initiating into the class. This includes becoming a Shadow Weave user.

Thus, an oathbreaking Knight of the Weave can continue to use their powers and even continue to take levels in the class.

That said, I do not recommend making this technicality in the rules as the basis of your argument. When discussing rules with your table, you should advocate for what rules best serve the game you all want to play, and explain why your interpretation better fits that than another interpretation. There are no RAW police who will slap your DM's hand or take away their cookies if you try to argue this technicality and they say "No, that doesn't make sense with the world I'm trying to portray," and house-rule it.

### However, I think things work better if players are allowed to adjudicate their own restrictions

In my games, I leave the details of behavioral restrictions imposed by a class up to their player - the player of a paladin gets to decide what would or would not violate their oath, for example. I rarely overrule anyone, but if their interpretation of a restriction wildly differs from mine, I would certainly talk to them about it.

I think it is better for the game if a player is never surprised by their behavioral restrictions. After all, their PC should be the expert in their own oaths, so I don't want to create a situation where the PC would be wrong about them.

Comment: The middle section is wrong. The rules don’t support the DM at all—they say you need to meet the requirements to take the 1st level of the class. Once you have, the rules never suggest that the requirements have any significance at all. The rest, of course, is exactly right.

Comment: @KRyan the section "Playing a Knight of the Weave" supports this answer. Unless you disregard it as meaningless fluff, of course. But then, what's the point of portraying Shadow Weave as evil, bad etc anyway?

Comment: @KRyan - You're exactly right. I actually considered mentioning that in my answer, but I didn't include it because I didn't think it would be useful (I don't think the asker is looking for a technicality that allows them to ignore the restriction, and I don't think debating technicalities at the table is good gameplay). That said, it is *correct*, so if you want to post that as a competing answer, I'd upvote it regardless.

Comment: The “Playing a...” sections aren’t meaningless, but they aren’t straightjackets either. I would, generally speaking, say it is extremely bad idea to read them as requirements. (E.g. requiring sorcerers to be jealous of duskblades, as stated in _PHB2_, would be a horrendous ruling.) On the other hand, I could imagine exceptions, but since your answer makes no reference to it, and I am away from my books at the moment, I don’t really know what support may be there. I think an acknowledgement of the official rules, which explicitly contradict the DM, needs to say least caveat the middle section.

Comment: And also any reference to text that supports the DM, to counterbalance that, should be explicit in the answer, e.g. whatever is in the “Playing a...” bit. Also, I would point out that it isn’t exactly nonsense for someone to swear to do or not do things in order to get admission to the Order, and then just... not. Plenty of things in D&D have you automatically lose powers when you do something like that, but things don’t **have to** work that way. So the RAW approach isn’t like, impossible in the narrative or anything.

Comment: A quick link to the [canonical Q&A on prestige class requirements](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/41888/4563) might be the easiest way to handle things, if you wanted.

Comment: @KRyan - Thanks for that link. I am *also* away from my books (they're all packed up in storage after a move), so I don't have access to the "Playing a Knight of the Weave" text, unfortunately, but I've added the technical caveat.